# Something related to/comes from our wisdom?

Tags: word-choice

I know the meaning of `wisdom`. Also know the meaning of `thought`. While we want to say that something needs us to think a lot about it, we use `thoughtful`. So how about wisdom? Which word should we use about something that is coming from/related to wisdom?

Does "Intellectual" has the complete meaning? Is there any other word with better meaning?

**Edit 1 (usage):**
I'm going to describe my premise in English that:
There are two types of contents.

- **Instinctual Contents** which are related to our instinct and are historical.
- **Intellectual Contents** which are related to our **wisdom** and are futurism.

I don't know if `intellectual` is an appropriate word in this case.

**Edit 2:**
`Cerebral` is related to physical brain. `Wisdom` is metaphysical.
`Intelligent` is about to recognize, `Wisdom` is about to judge or decide.
`Behavior` is the result of our thoughts, feelings and operations, `Wisdom` is about how to behave.

Comment: Do you mean other than *wise*:  His decision was very *wise*.

Comment: *Thoughtful* does not describe objects of thought, matters which require a lot of thought, but subjects of thought, people who think a lot or discourses which exhibit the results of a great deal of thought.

Comment: @Jim I think "wise" is something related to "wisdom"

Comment: @StoneyB How to say that something is related to our wisdom? Is it true to say "That's Intellectual"?

Comment: @Omid- Exactly. Isn't that what you're asking about?  To say something is related to wisdom, you say, "That's wise." E.g., "That was a very wise choice." means your choice displayed a lot of wisdom.

Comment: @Jim I made an edit which can help the question to be more clear.

Comment: @Omid- I'm not sure this is really the direction you wanted to go, but when contrasting behaviors there are *instinctive* behaviors and *learned* behaviors.

Comment: How about something like, *cerebral*?

Comment: @Jim No, That's different why we talk about behavior. Behavior is the result of our thoughts, feeling and operations. And about cerebral, it seems, it's related to physical brain. Wisdom is metaphysical.

Comment: @Omid- *Intelligent*??  otherwise I don't think I understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with StoneyB and Omid, you got it right - the word *wise* can go there. But then I think you are searching for something that shows that **it requires wisdom.**

First look at the word you are sure about.

> [Wisdom](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/wisdom?showCookiePolicy=true) - the quality of being wise; power of judging rightly and following the soundest course of action, based on knowledge, experience, understanding, etc.; good judgment; **sagacity.**

Nevertheless, I could find two better words close to what you are looking for.

> **[Sapient (Adj.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sapient))** - having or showing great wisdom or sound judgment. 
>   AND
>   **[Sapient (Adj.)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sapient)** - possessing or expressing great sagacity.

OR you may go for...

> **[Sagacious](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/SAGACIOUS) (adj.)**: acutely insightful and wise

The origin of *sapient* as described in [Marriem Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sapient)

`Middle English, from Middle French, from Latin sapient-, sapiens, from present participle of sapere to taste, be wise`

Let me try to get you an example -

> *"When there are too many patients getting admitted to this hospital, our management goes haywire. We need something to stop this." 
>
>   "Why don't we recruit more managers?."* 
>  
>   *"Nah, it's not easy as you think."* 
>   *"True, it requires **sapient** approach."*
>   *"Let's go for Bed Management System (BMS) then.*

Comment: @MualikV Thanks. could you please read the edited question ?

Comment: @Omid Don't you think *sapient content* can go there?

Comment: @MualikV I'm not sure what do you mean by `Sapient Content`. What type of content is that?

Comment: @Omid The content that's insightful and wise. You can also go for the word *sagacious* as described there. As in - *observant and thoughtful, he was given to asking sagacious questions*

Answer (score 0):

On a frivolous note, Dungeons and Dragons has a Wisdom statistic, and an Intelligent statistic for characters.  A character with a high Intelligence value would know that a tomato is scientifically a fruit, a character with a High Wisdom value would know that you still don't make fruit salad with tomatoes.